# price range problem

Tags: php

I am developing an application which deals with commission based on price range

I have 2 text-boxes (input type="text"), one for lower-limit, and another for upper-limit

Everytime someone adds new price range, I need to validate that it is available before hand or not, and whether it will fall in any of the previous price range

Example for Valid Ranges:
1-10
11-20
21-30
31-40

what should not be allowed are:
(considering following range is available with us
1-10
11-20
21-30
31-40
)
following should not be allowed
0-5
2-8
0-15
5-12

Help appriciated.

Comment: Maybe you could specify your question and your problem. What are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

If the available ranges are predefined and known, why not simply replace the two text boxes with a single select box with an `<option>` for each range?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following php code on your page

```
$ranges = array('1-10','11-20','21-30','31-40');

echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var ranges = [". "'" .implode("','",$ranges) . "'" . "];</script>";
```

Assuming your textboxes have ids lowerlimit and upperlimit you can simply check before submit

```
function check(){
  var lowerlimit = document.getElementById('lowerlimit').value;
  var upperlimit = document.getElementById('upperlimit ').value;
  for (var i=0; i<ranges.length; i++) {
    if(ranges[i] == lowerlimit+'-'+uperlimit){
       return true;
    }
  }
  return false; 
}

if (!check()){
   alert('Please enter valid range!')
}
```